# ASP.NET MVC Html.Display() using ViewData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I use Html.DisplayFor() using a property of the model, it comes out nicely with both a label for the property name and a textbox or label with the property value:

```
Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)     // renders as First Name: Joe Smith
```

But if I try to use the same for something that is in ViewData, it doesn't seem to have any way to specify the text that will be used in the label in the rendered html:

```
Html.Display(ViewData["something"].ToString())     // renders as (no label) something
```

The other Html.Display() parameters don't look helpful:

```
Html.Display(ViewData["something"].ToString(), "TemplateName", "HtmlElementId", {additionalData})
```

It looks like the only place I might pass the label is with the additionalData param, but I haven't found any examples or docs on how to do this.

Answer (score 11):

Html.Display() takes a string *expression* of what to find in the viewdata and not the view data itself.

You want:

```
Html.Display("something");
```

Comment: Yes I typed it wrong in the question.  But this doesn't answer the question. I know how to display the value, its the label that I cant automatically create with either Label() or LabelFor() (of course I can always manually type in the label text myself)

Comment: Sorry meant to say "with either Display() or DisplayFor()" (not Label)